# jquery submit function opening up pop up - need to open up in a new tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

My site is http://www.tripconnects.com. I am trying to create a login process in which when a user logs into my site, it will be logged into a third site also. I am using jquery submit()
function to submit the form for authentication on third site. But when the submit event is fired it tries to open a popup. I've added the target="_blank" attribute to form also, but nothing seems to work. Here is my jQuery code :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    if ($(".adlogin .readon .button").length == 1) {
        $.ajax({
            url : '/adlogin_ajax.php',
            method : 'post',
            success : function(response){
                if(response == 'true'){
                    $("#ssoform").submit();
                }
                return false;
             }
        }); 
    }  
});
```

Please Help.
Thanks!

Comment: Check this first:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: I dont want to open a link in new tab but I want to submit a form in new tab.

Comment: try using async = false;

Comment: yes, it is just like another attribute

Comment: If I click the button to submit form, it opens up new tab. async = false not working either. I tried trigger('click') also, but none of all these is working.

Comment: My point was that you have not necessarily control over if form is opening a new window or not. But that being said now I think fully understand what you want to do. :D I will put an answer below in a few minutes.

Comment: `target="_blank"` should be all that you need.  Have you tried it on a different browser?

Comment: target="_blank" is not also working.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are want to do following:

As user logs in on your site you want to fill login form on the other site with credentials provided on yours and press submit.

What you doing right now is to using ajax, get content of target site, and submit form. This will trigger new popup/tab with answer from that site.

Solution.

First check where the form on target site is pointing you. After pressing submit there is some kind of url (intercept that url in console/terminal in google chrome or firefox).

Then to something like:

```
$.post("<interecepted_url.php>", {login: "mylogin", password: "mypass"})
.done(function() {
   alert( "second success" )
})
.fail(function() {
   alert( "error" )
})
.always(function() {
   alert( "finished" )
})
```

However this solution is a bit hackish, because you are making cross domain requests, it may be over ssl, csrf protection that sort of the problem. Nevertheless sometimes man has to do what man has to do. ;)

In general what you want to do is not open some kind of site, find a form and submit it, but pretend to be that site, forge a request and post it, receive the answer and process that answer on your site.

Let me know, if it helps.